# Upgrading from Version 18.04 LTS to 18.10 fails: Could not calculate the upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ppa

I get this error when I try to upgrade ubuntu

Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was likely caused by:
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

[image]

Comment: How do you run the upgrade?

Comment: Alt+f2 then type update-manager -c and click upgrade

Comment: Upgrading from LTS to non-LTS is a bad idea. You lose 5 years of support and obtain only the pain.

Comment: Have you tried to do the ppa-purge? Also, you may be able to get away with just disabling those software sources from the Ubuntu software repository (for the unsupported apps). It may allow you to do the upgrade then, but at the risk of breaking something later.